# When to use return in Sequelize promises?

Tags: javascript, database, postgresql, promise, sequelize.js

I am new to Sequelize and Promises which can be slightly a bit confusing for someone who is not very familiar with them and the javaScript language. Anyway, I have noticed that in some implementation of promises, the "return" is used. In other implementations it is not.
For example:

```
 //FILL JOIN TABLE FROM EXISTING DATA
  Blog.find({where: {id: '1'}}) .then(blog => {
    return Tag.find({where: {id: '1'}}).then(tag => {
      return blog.hasTag(tag).
      then(result => {
        // result would be false BECAUSE the blog.addTag is still not used yet
        console.log("3 RESULT IS"+ result);
        return blog.addTag(tag).
        then(() => {
          return blog.hasTag(tag).
          then(result => {
            // result would be true
            console.log("4 RESULT IS"+ result);
          })
        })
      })
    })
  })
```

And here: They are not used.

```
const tags = body.tags.map(tag => Tag.findOrCreate({ where: { name: tag }, defaults: { name: tag }})
                                        .spread((tag, created) => tag))

   User.findById(body.userId)    //We will check if the user who wants to create the blog actually exists
       .then(() => Blog.create(body))
       .then(blog => Promise.all(tags).then(storedTags => blog.addTags(storedTags)).then(() => blog/*blog now is associated with stored tags*/)) //Associate the tags to the blog
       .then(blog => Blog.findOne({ where: {id: blog.id}, include: [User, Tag]})) // We will find the blog we have just created and we will include the corresponding user and tags
       .then(blogWithAssociations => res.json(blogWithAssociations)) // we will show it
       .catch(err => res.status(400).json({ err: `User with id = [${body.userId}] doesn\'t exist.`}))
      };
```

Can someone please explain to me the use of "return"? It is obviously not necessary since the second code works? So when do I have to use it?
Thank you!!

Comment: in this `() => Blog.create(body)` form of arrow functions, there **is an implied return** ... it's essentially `() => { return Blog.create(body);}` - so, the question is really nothing to do with sequelize or promises, it's more to do with javascript [arrow function syntax as documented here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Oh okaaay thank youuu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, you asked about **arrow function**.

```js
const dummyData = { foo: "lorem" };

const af1 = () => dummyData;

const af2 = () => {
    dummyData.foo = "bar";
    return dummyData;
};

const af3 = () => { foo: "bar" };

const af4 = () => ({
    foo: "bar"
});

console.log(af1()); 

console.log(af2()); 

console.log(af3()); // Be aware if you wanna return something's started with bracket

console.log(af4());
```

As you see, we use `return` statement in `af1` because we have to write another "logic" before return a value. If you don't do that, you can avoid using `return` statement (it could improve your code simplicity and readable).